# Understanding the meaning of the following method in linux/bash

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, echo

```
DB_USER = 'db_user'
DB_PASS = 'db_pass'
DB_HOST = 'db_host'
DB = 'db'

function dbConnection() {
 echo "$1" | mysql -u${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASS} -h${DB_HOST} ${DB} -N
}
```

Request you to ignore the actual values of the db variables.
I wanted to understand the meaning of the above method. I have the following doubts:

1. What is echo "$1" doing here?
2. Why are we using the pipe operator?
3. And what is the relation between the echo command and the mysql command?

Comment: Hi Guys. instead of downvoting my question, can you atleast suggest the possible solutions?

Comment: See [How to handle "explain how ${this code dump} works" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta] -- such questions are almost always too broad to be on-topic unless you describe exactly what you already do understand and exactly where that understanding fails.

Comment: BTW, this code has a lot of bugs and won't actually work. `var = value` isn't a valid assignment in bash; it needs to be `var=value` _without the spaces_. Parameter expansions need to be quoted to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion. Less critically, all-caps names are in a reserved namespace (used for variables like PATH that change the behavior of the shell and operating system tools) and shouldn't be used for locally-defined variables -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html establishing relevant conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql` is able to read queries from stdin and `|` connects the **stdout** of the left-hand side command to the **stdin** of the right-hand side command. So `echo "$1"` will write a query (the first argument passed to `dbConnection`) to stdout which will be then read by the `mysql` command from its stdin.

Comment: But it seems like the mysql command is establishing a connection here. What will the mysql command do with the input received (the query)  ? Can you please break it down a little more?

Comment: Thanks for the answer above. Cleared up some of my doubts

Comment: @joeylang yes, it's establishing a connection and then it executes the query read from stdin. At the end, the connection is closed. Try it using something like this: `echo 'select 1 + 1' | mysql ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it some valid SQL.

```
dbConnection "SELECT 1+2;"
```

The string passed becomes the argument passed in.

```
echo "$1"
```

becomes (effectively)

```
echo "SELECT 1+2;"
```

which the pipe then connects to mysql`'s stdin - it becomes the input to the program.

It's the script to execute.